# Change Facebook Customer Chat Plugin Icon to a Custom One

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, iframe, facebook-customer-chat

Any ideas on how to change Facebook Customer Chat Plugin icon to a custom one?

The whole Facebook customer chat is loaded over iframe, so it seems there is not much to do there, I've tried placing my own icon on top of it and use "pointer-events: none;" so the original Facebook icon would be clicked, but the problem is that my icon has transparent parts and you can see the original icon underneath.

Has anyone tried this and has any ideas on what could work?

Comment: There isn’t anything else than overlaying some element on top of it; and even with that I’d be extremely careful, it might trigger detection as clickjacking. Plus, Facebook does not allow you to change anything about the appearance of their social plugins, other than the options/settings offered for that.